# Windows Spotlight wallpapers on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, desktop-background

Windows 10 update kb3081436 added dynamic wallpaper changes on login/lock screen.
The photos are really awesome. 
[image]

Does exist some script to take those photos and uses them as Ubuntu wallpaper

http://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-windows-spotlight

Comment: While there are not exacte same images, it is tool for the job!

Comment: I think you can add your own sources to the tool, and the sources of Windows backgrounds are well, a Windows question and for [su]...